# Stuck when installing cordova

Tags: node.js, cordova

I'm following the step on the homepage of cordova, but I am confuse at first step! I typed `sudo npm install -g cordova` in terminal, but it stuck

> loadDep:xtend → network   ▌ ╢████████████░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░╟

It takes hours but no further progress. Actually, I'm in China and I guess it may be caused by network issue. But I turn VPN on and I'm able to visit Google. Then, I have no idea what to do now. Please give me some hints, thanks!

Comment: try `-d` or `--verbose` flag for more info

Comment: I use `-d` this time, and there are many timeout occurred. It still stuck at here:                                                                                                           npm http request GET https://registry.npmjs.org/hash.js
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/hash.js
loadDep:hash.js → network ▌ ╢████████████░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░╟

Answer (score 1):

use this command in command prompt:

```
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

change the configuration its work for me

Answer (score 1):

use this command in command prompt

```
npm set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
```

and then try to install it again using the below command

```
npm install -g cordova@latest
```